# CAKEPHP Stucked in Associating Models

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Im using cakephp and Im stuck about the idea of listing multiple models, here's my scenario:

I have two major models namely Task and Events. I used the Events model to track all changes. this has the ff fields: id, model, model_id, changed
I used Events table to track multiple model changes. so when something changed to Task model it will be logged to Events models (get the idea??)

What I want to do is whenever i used the find method for Event model, i want to list the model information (for example, the Task model) together with my Events information like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array (
        [Event] => array(
            id => 1
            model => Task
            model_id => 2
            changed => array()
        )

        [Task] => array(
            id => 2
            name => Task 1
            descp => Test Task
        )

    )
)
```

Note: The model can be any model, it can be Projects model.

At my task.php, it is no problem because i can easily declare:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Events' => array(
            'className' => 'Events',
            'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Events.model' => 'Task')
        )
    );
```

I can get Events information using the find method on task although using

```
 $this->Task->Event->find('all');
```

will not work, i dont know why.

So as soon as I declare, something like this in my Event Model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Task' => array(
        'className' => 'Task',
        'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
        'conditions' => array('Event.model' => 'Task', 'Event.model_id' => 'Task.id'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

will throw an SQL error. Do you guys have an idea how to implement it?? 
Thanks in advanced. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use polymorphic models all the time. The reason that `$this->Task->Event->find('all')` doesn't work is that you were performing the find on the `Event` model which, until you defined its `belongsTo` association, didn't have any means of retrieving the `Task` info.

As for now, the only thing I see that looks odd is that you've aliased your `Task` association as `Events` (plural) rather than its singular version which is the convention for models. You also identified the `className` as the plural version.

Comment: yes man! it worked! the little "s" problem was the culprit., ive removed the plural forms on my model and it worked man! thank you very much., I'll also apply similar association to other models.. Thank you man! Im jumping in joy right now.. :))